# Is it possible that `pre-commit autoupdate` skips a single linter?

Tags: pre-commit, pre-commit.com

One of the projects I maintain still needs to provide Python 2.7 compatibility.

I use `pre-commit` with `black` and `black` dropped Python 2 support, so I want to stay on e.g. `black` version `21.9b0`, but still I'd like to use `pre-commit autoupdate` to update the other linters.

I have seen the `freeze` command for `pre-commit` but this still updates my `black` version:

```
-   repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 911470a610e47d9da5ea938b0887c3df62819b85 # frozen: 21.9b0
    hooks:
    -   id: black
        additional_dependencies: ['click<8.1']
```

FWIW: I created the above snippet manually.

```
❯ pre-commit autoupdate
Updating https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks ... already up to date.
Updating https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8 ... already up to date.
Updating https://github.com/psf/black ... updating 911470a610e47d9da5ea938b0887c3df62819b85 -> 22.10.0.
Updating https://github.com/get-woke/woke ... already up to date.
```

Is it possible to just skip one linter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such option -- it's **auto**update not **manual**update

you can always `git checkout -p` the changes you don't want -- though it's almost 2023 and time to let python 2 go

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I think [`pre-commit-update`](https://pypi.org/project/pre-commit-update/) can help in your specific case. You can "pin" a single hook and avoid updates on it.